# Flash action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript

Is it possible to get list of Active directory users from server using Flash actionscript 3.0.
Please share if any URL for reference or sample script to connect AD server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting on a webserver, you could ofcourse use PHP and create a bridge to flash/actionscript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i was actually looking if i can use action script bridge itself. Iam sorry, i should have mentioned Adobe AIR instead of flash. The client wants a standalone flash file (probably they have no idea that we can create a standalon file using Air) that can query the Active directory and throw up some results.